# Ubuntu 12.04 gnome issue, no clock is shown, strange starter icon cannot be removed

Tags: indicator

i am finding nowhere a solution
I am running UBUNTU 12.04 and using GNOME desktop, which I installed additionally.
Logging into classic GNOME I see the following:

[image: screengrab of toolbar]

1. WHAT is this "earth globe" icon coming from?Seems to be named "starter". It is configured to open a website, from my bookmarks.
2. WHY is it not showing the TIME?

Using dconf-editor I had no luck in answering the above questions.

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

New answer:

Go to a blank space on the panel, press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Click</kbd> and `Add to panel`, then choose the **Clock** and `Add`, like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKEua.jpg)

Older answer:

> **1)** hold these keys on the icon: <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right Click</kbd> and click
>   remove or something similar.
>
> **2)** open a terminal and type
>
> `sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime`
>
> or
>
> `sudo apt-get install --reinstall indicator-datetime`
>
> logout or restart your pc.